# Leaflet - modal opens behind map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, leaflet

I'm using `leaflet` and [modalcss](https://github.com/pedrolaxe/modalcss) to display a modal within a map.
This worked like a charm with `leaflet` v0.7.7. See this Plunker: [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/logpfGtVXrv9JUtEGDrF?p=preview)
--> Click the button under the zoom controls.

When I switch to `leaflet` v1.2.0 the modal gets opened but behind the map. See this Plunker: [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/R85hZ2mNU9cCAeakGcu9?p=preview)

Why is this happening?
Any idea on how to show the modal in front of the map like in the old version of `leaflet`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply this CSS rules to map and model:

```
#map{ z-index:1; }
#modal{ z-index:2; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why this is different in the old and new versions of leaflet?

Comment: @duenni: see [Leaflet #3690](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3690) and [#5193](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5193)